# Flickr API tag search (jQuery/ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

So I have a simple search form at the top of my document which is ment for tags. It looks like this:

```
<div id="search">
    <form id="srch">
        <input type="text" placeholder="No filthy keywords pls." id="sbx"/>
            <a href="" type="submit" id="btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </form>
</div>
```

And I want the user to write a tag into the "search" field and when he presses the submit button it gets the photos based on the tag he supplied and fetches photos from flickr and fills a **#container div** with them. The jQuery I have so far looks like this:

```
var searchTerm = $("#sbx").val();
var Flickurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=376b144109ffe90065a254606c9aae3d&";
var tags = "&tags=" + searchTerm;
var tagmode = "&tagmode=any";
var jsonFormat = "&format=json";
var FinalURL = Flickurl + tags + tagmode + jsonFormat;

$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btn").click(function(event){
          $.getJSON('FinalURL', function(photo) {
             $('#content').append('<img src="' + 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/' + photo.owner + '/' +  photo.id + '"/>');
          });
      });
   });
```

I cannot find any help anywhere, I'm doing this as a schools project and I have never, ever done anything with API's I think I'm misunderstanding something in the jquery and api documentation because this is not doing anything at all lol..

I will be super happy if there is anyone who could help me with this, I feel like the code should be good but maybe I'm missing something small.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the string 'FinalURL', which will be resolved to `CURRENT_URL/FinalURL`, try this

```
$.getJSON(FinalURL, ... (without the quotes ')
```

Ok i found some other errors too.

- Change your `var jsonFormat` to this `"&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"` to get jsonrawdata from the api.
- The json returned isn't one photo, it's a list of all photos, so to access one photo you have to do this: `response.photos.photo[NUMBER]`
- Your url is pointing to a flickr page and not to an image source, it should be like this: `https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg`

I fixed your errors in this fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1veacqu/)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding to this, finally I moved somewhere now I just have to adjust it so that it loads more images at once :) but seriously thank you so much! I was standing in place for so long, I owe you a beer lol. I obviously didn't understand how to pull the data from json I just thought I can access it directly but apparently not :S THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this will work. You just needed to change how you were populating the url queries into a javascript object.

http://jsfiddle.net/669jy9am/

Obviously this won't work on JSFiddle, but if you put that into your own page, it should work.

```
<div id="search">
<form class="search--form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="No filthy keywords pls." id="sbx" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Search<i class="fa fa-search"></i>

    </button>
</form>
```

```
function searchFlickr() {
 var searchTerm = $("#sbx").val();
 var Flickurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=376b144109ffe90065a254606c9aae3d&";



 $("form").submit(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var searchTerm = $('#sbx').val();
     $.ajax({
         url: 'Flickrurl',
         data: {
             format: "json",
             jsoncallback: 1,
             tags: searchTerm
         },
     }).done(function (data) {
         //Populate the images with the data
     });
 });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    searchFlickr();
});
```

Comment: His way of populating the url is valid, though this looks better :). This still just fetches the string 'Flickrurl'.